# LIMIT and Contains in a single JSONB Query

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have 2 queries that separately run perfectly:

This one limits the results:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(elem) as data
FROM  (
  SELECT *
  FROM file_data, jsonb_array_elements(file_data) a(elem)
  LIMIT 3
) sub;
```

This one correctly runs a 'contains' filter:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(obj)
FROM file_data, jsonb_array_elements(file_data) obj
WHERE obj->>'first_name' LIKE '%M%';
```

How do I combine these so that I can "select data where the first name contains M, and limit the result to X rows"?

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b29c/30) with fake data to test it on. I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `limit` a subquery before aggregating:

```
select jsonb_agg(obj)
from (
    select obj
    from file_data, jsonb_array_elements(file_data) obj
    where obj->>'first_name' LIKE '%M%'
    limit 3
 ) x ;
```

Note: you probably want to add an `order by` clause in the subquery; without it, it is not possible to predict *which* 3 records will be picked.

Comment: Agh, I was so close. I tried something similar but it returned `null` so I threw it away. You're absolutely right though, this will be combined with a sort method so that there is some form of predictability in what's returning. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @SterlingArcher!

Answer (score 1):

you can limit your `json_agg` result based on `row_number()` of your `subquery`

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(elem order by elem->>'id' DESC) as data
FROM  (
  SELECT elem
    , row_number() over (order by elem->>'id') as rn
  FROM file_data
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(file_data) a(elem)
  WHERE elem->>'first_name' LIKE '%M%'     
) subs 
WHERE rn <= 3;
```